# Sharing the Application URI Scheme Registration on Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, registry, protocols, url-scheme

I'm writing an application which registers the "tel" protocol on Windows 8 so when I open Start > Run, enter tel:1234 and hit Enter my application gets launched and makes a phone call to 1234. This works successfully on XP, Win7 and Win8. However, on Win8 I have found that when I install Google Chrome it "takes over" the handling of the tel protocol so when I run tel:1234 again Chrome is launched instead of my application. Chrome does not take over the tel protocol in Win7 or XP. I'd like to understand what the issue is.

Currently my application registers the tel protocol by adding the following registry entries as described in [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel
@="URL:My Tel Protocol Handler"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\MyTelProtocol.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\MyTelProtocol.exe\" -URI %1"
```

I have found that Google Chrome doesn't overwrite my registry data with its own. Instead it appears to register the protocol handler in a different way, but I can't figure out how to do the same. Would anyone have an idea why Windows 8 is handling this differently?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the "tel" registry key which Chrome adds during its installation.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google
>   Chrome\Capabilities\UrlAssociations

After that, you need to push win 8 to relaod registry base (restarting or some other way) and jabber will become default app for TEL:URI ;).

Comment: It is not acceptable to delete another applications registration like this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some guidance on the [File type and protocol associations model (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which seems to apply to Windows 8. Maybe try that?

[This codereview](https://codereview.chromium.org/11127002/patch/16001/17002) suggests that the code for Chrome's protocol handlers sits in [this file](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/installer/util/shell_util.cc?view=markup), in case it's of any use.